# Oracle parameterize finding column count of a table - ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-00905

I am adding a number of columns to multiple tables. Before I add them, I want to make sure they don't exist already.

```
SELECT count(*)
INTO myCount
FROM user_tab_cols
WHERE column_name = 'newCol'
  and table_name = 'tableName';
```

Since the only variables are the `tableName` and `columnName`, I thought of parameterizing these two variables hoping to reuse it. So I wrote a pl/sql:

```
DECLARE
 myCount      NUMBER;
 COUNT_COLUMN VARCHAR2(1000) :=
        ' SELECT count(*)
    INTO myCount
    FROM user_tab_cols
    WHERE column_name = :1
      and table_name = :2';


BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE COUNT_COLUMN using 'columnName','tableName';
/*code to check count and add column*/

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(myCount);


EXCEPTION
    WHEN
        OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'sql failed: ' || SQLCODE || ': ' || SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200));
END;
```

I expected the `myCount` variable to contain number of columns in a table. But I get the following error.

> sql failed: -905: ORA-00905: missing keyword

How do I get rid of this error? what other ways do I have to achieve this?

Comment: Would it not be simpler to just try adding the column and catch any error of "that table already contains that column" and ignore it?

Comment: The thing is there are multiple add/remove operations. Writing a try-catch block for every add/remove will make the code look clumsy.

Comment: So, PLSQL has loops..

Comment: Also, why does this even need dynamic sql/execute immediate for the select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INTO cluase must not be included in SQL query but to be used in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement. So, You need to fix your dynamic SQL as below -

```
DECLARE
 myCount      NUMBER;
 COUNT_COLUMN VARCHAR2(1000) :=
        ' SELECT count(*)
    FROM user_tab_cols
    WHERE column_name = :1
      and table_name = :2';

BEGIN            -- Add the BEGIN keyword to complete a PL/SQL block

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE COUNT_COLUMN INTO myCount using 'columnName','tableName';
/*code to check count and add column*/

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(myCount);


EXCEPTION
    WHEN
        OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'sql failed: ' || SQLCODE || ': ' || SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200));
END;
```

Comment: I had BEGIN in the statement. Missed it while writing the question!

Comment: @ArunGowda, No Issue. Happy coding.